# Why isn't border showing?

Tags: css

No matter what I try, I cannot get my CSS grid to display borders around its cells. Has never been a problem in the past - just suddenly stopped working!

```
.box {
  background-color: #F5F5F6;
  color: #0071FF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
  border: 1px solid black;  
}
```

Comment: [Works OK for me](https://jsfiddle.net/zap6dv3x/), so we're missing context / MCVE.

Comment: could be overwriting. try  border: 1px solid black !important;

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about that?

```css
table tr{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

table td{
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-left: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 -1px;
}

table td:first-child{
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Title</td>
      <td>Title</td>
      <td>Title</td>
      <td>Title</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```